# Exclude paths in SpringBoot Trace end point

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to exclude some paths from SpringBoot trace end point (because they make noise on the monitor view). I couldn't find the guideline from Spring document for doing this. Is there any way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean exclude the logs in some paths?!

Comment: Here you can see that the framework trace the http requests, and I want some parts (e.g. /version, /heath....) are excluded from tracing. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html